# Asymptotics of function

Tags: analysis, asymptotics

For each positive $k$ consider  $0 \leq x \leq k$ and the family of equations defined on these domains
\begin{align}
f_k(x)=x \left(1-\log\left[ \frac{x}{k} \right] \right).
\end{align}

Now denote by $x^*(k)$ the value of $x$ such that
\begin{align}
f_k(x) =x \left(1-\log\left[ \frac{x}{k} \right] \right) = c \log(k).
\end{align}
This always exists for $k$ large enough, since $f_k$ is monotonically increasing from $0$ to $k$ and assumes all values from $0$ to $k$, while $\log(k)$ grows slower than $k$.

My question is, what can we say about the asymptotics of $x^*(k)$?
E.g. $x^*(k) \sim \log k?$ or $x^*(k) \sim \log \log k$? Or something else? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can re-write your equation as
$$
\frac{{x^ *  }}{{ek}}\log \left( {\frac{{x^ *  }}{{ek}}} \right) =  - \frac{{c\log k}}{{ek}}.
$$
Thus, in terms of the Lambert-$W$ function,
$$
x^ *   = k\exp \left( {1 + W\!\left( { - \frac{{c\log k}}{{ek}}} \right)} \right).
$$
You may use the Maclaurin series of $W$ to obtain simplifed approximations for $x^\ast$.

Comment: wonderful, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Calling $u = \log(k)$ we have

$$ x ( 1-\log(x) +u) = c u \implies u = \frac{\log(x)-1}{1-c/x}$$

If $c$ is fixed, for large $x$ this grows as $(\log(x)-1)(1 + c/x)$ which gives

$$ k \approx  \frac{x}{e}\left(1+ c \frac{\log(x)}{x}\right) $$

Hence I'd expect

$$x \approx  e\, k - c \log(k)$$

or $x \sim  e\, k $